# Generate select without optgroup on dropDownList in Yii

Tags: php, html, yii

I am using dropDownListRow of bootstrap Yii.

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'roles', array('' => "--Select Roles--", 'Trekking Agency' => CHtml::listData(Roles::model()->findAll(), 'idRole', 'name'))); ?>
```

It renders my select within the optgroup. I do not want the options in optgroup. What is the way to remove optgroup from the select in Yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `ListData` within an array and that array has another element, optgroups will be created if you have an array within array structure. For creating empty options use empty `htmlOptions` attribute as below ([see here for details)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail)

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'roles', 
                 CHtml::listData(Roles::model()->findAll(), 'idRole', 'name'),
                 array('empty'=>'--Select Roles---')); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. But one thing is when I use this dropDownListRow() of bootstrap, it produces extra options of 'Roles' at the end.

Comment: That only happens to me when empty is not set, otherwise it works fine.. perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: It generates extra options <option value="placeholder">Roles</option> at the end of the select options.

Comment: try giving "placeholder"=>"" in addition to "empty"=>"--Select Roles--" in the htmlOptions array

Comment: It's kind of weird. When i add placeholder in htmlOptions array, it adds the placeholder to <select> tag. When I use dropDownList() only it doesnot generate that placeholder options at the last but when I use dropDownListRow() which is of bootstrap Yii, it generates that options.

Comment: perhaps it is a bug in yii-bootstrap, you can try the latest version for bootstrap 2 (that would be 3.1.1 of Yii booster), Once i give 'empty' or 'select' the placeholder goes away for me in this version

Comment: Perhaps. Thanks. I will try with latest version of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Yii 2.0++
And `items = array(arra(item01=>1), array(item02=>2))`

you need this:

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

<?= Html::dropDownList('Name', 'SelectedItem', ArrayHelper::getColumn($listItems, 'key_name')); ?>
```